# Delete record from a sql table by selecting from gridview on button click

Tags: c#

I want to delete a record from a datagridview that's in one form by pressing a button in another form. But I am getting a `nullreferenceexception was unhandled` error. I am new to c# so if someone could write me the correct code I would really appreciate it.

Here's what I got so far.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@" Data Source=HOME-D2CADC8D4F\SQL;Initial Catalog=motociclete;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
        if (dr.Selected == true)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "Delete from motociclete where codm=" + i + "";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the exception at? I also noticed that you are referring to multiple forms here. A little more info on that front might help us.

Comment: I get the exception at this line:  for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)

Comment: When you get an exception, you get a line number which tells you exactly where it happens. It's helpful if you set a breakpoint on that line and then run the code to find out what's happened to cause the exception. It's also extremely helpful if you identify that line for us in your question (not in the comments, but in the question itself) by commenting or otherwise marking that line so we don't have to guess. After all, you know *exactly which line*, because the exception gives you that information. Please share it with us.

Answer (score 1):

Just invert the verse of the loop.

```
 for (int i = dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
```

In this way your loop is not affected by the changing number of rows

Also. This is the case where I would not open/close the connection at every command execution, and the command execution could be more performant if you use a parameter in this way

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@" Data Source=HOME-D2CADC8D4F\SQL;Initial Catalog=motociclete;Integrated Security=True"))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Delete from motociclete where codm=@id", con))
{
    con.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 0);
    for (int i = dataGridView1.Rows.Count-1; i >= 0; i++)
    {
        DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
        if (dr.Selected == true)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = i;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The only possibility to get a NullReferenceException on the `for(i = dateGridView1.Rows.Count-1` line is due to the Rows or the datagridview are null.

Comment: I have data in the sql table and it's shown in the datagridview , so i don't think that is the problem.

Comment: Then the only thing to help clear the problem is the debugger. Set a breakpoint on the offending line and check where is the null value

Answer (score 0):

You are removing rows while iterating over them and that causes `NullPointerException` because when you remove row, count is changing but loop is still going for as long as initial count.

One way of doing it is creating temporary list of rows and delete them after:

```
List<DataGridViewRow> rowstodelete = new List<DataGridViewRow>();

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView1.Rows[i];
    if (dr.Selected)
    {
        rowstodelete.Add(dr);
        try
        {
              con.Open();
              cmd.CommandText = "Delete from motociclete where codm=" + i + "";
              cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
              con.Close();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
         }
    }
}

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in rowstodelete)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(row);
}
```

Comment: I still get the same error at this line: for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++) , after i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count

Comment: Is `i` coerced to a string automatically when you concatentate it to the delete statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  int row =-1;   

      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@" Data Source=HOME-D2CADC8D4F\SQL;Initial Catalog=motociclete;Integrated Security=True");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    row = new_tab_Object.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

            if (row!= (-1))
            {

                new_tab_Object.Rows.RemoveAt(row);                
                row = -1;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "Delete from motociclete where codm=" + row + "";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }

    this.Close();
  }
```

thy this...

Comment: I get an error at row and new_tab_Object.CurrentCell.RowIndex

Comment: replace new_tab_Object  with your gridview object  dr 

for ex    DataGridView dr = new DataGridView();

Comment: I still have the if(row) error. It says "cannot implicitly convert type 'int ' to 'bool'".Can you help me with that too?

Comment: It gives me a NullReferenceException at this line : row = new_tab_Object.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

Comment: for deleting the row you have to select one row or else it will throw an error..just select one row in your grid view and then press button  it will work..

Comment: It dosent. Is there something i can provide you with that might help you help me??

Answer (score 0):

Why do you loop through all rows, use dataGridView1.SelectedRows:

```
for (int i = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i]);
```

Also bind your data by using a DataTable and BindingSource.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to access the grid of one form from another. Make sure that you get the reference of your form (the one with the grid) properly and refer the grid using that. to achieve that you may have to expose your grid object as public.

In your parent form expose a property for the grid

```
public GridView Grid
{
    return dataGridView1;
}
```

..and when you launch the new form (say ChildForm) do like this

```
Form child = new ChildForm(this);
child.Show();
```

Please make changes to your child form to use the constructor argument.

```
private Form m_ParentForm;
public ChildForm(Form child)
{
   m_ParentForm = child;
}
```

..and your loop would look like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < m_ParentForm.Grid.Rows.Count; i++)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I thing it might be the connection from one form to another. Do i have to write Form parentForm = refObject; in the 1st form? And what is refObject?